# Division does not return a double

Tags: c#, double, rounding

The value of `fhr_1` below is calculated as 0.0
Why is `fhr_1` not 0.3?

```
        double fhr_1; 
        int n_fhr_1 = 9;
        int n_fhr_0 = 15;
        int n_fhr_2 = 6;

        fhr_1 = n_fhr_1/(n_fhr_1 + n_fhr_0 + n_fhr_2);
```

Comment: Is there a good reason why your variables are named like this? Aside from that they aren't using lowerCamelCase.

Comment: A more general answer to your question: the type of an expression does not depend on the type of the variable to which its result is being assigned.  In evaluating the right side of the assignment, the compiler does not look at the left side, so the fact that `fhr_1` is a double has no bearing on the evaluation of `n_fhr_1/(n_fhr_1 + n_fhr_0 + n_fhr_2)`.

Answer (score 7):

You need at least one operand of `double` type. Otherwise you will get integer result (integer division will happen)

```
fhr_1 = (double)n_fhr_1/(n_fhr_1 + n_fhr_0 + n_fhr_2);
```

Or

```
fhr_1 = n_fhr_1/(double)(n_fhr_1 + n_fhr_0 + n_fhr_2);
```

Or

```
fhr_1 = n_fhr_1 / ((double)n_fhr_1 + n_fhr_0 + n_fhr_2);
```

You can read more about division rules on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691373%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Comment: I like how you were the first to post and there is 3 more answers that essentially say the same thing.

Comment: @Nick I tend to agree with this kind of statement. However when other answers are posted a couple of seconds later, we can assume that they are not simple copy/paste of the original answer.

Comment: If that is the case please exclude those answers from my statement.

Answer (score 5):

```
double fhr_1; 
        int n_fhr_1 = 9;
        int n_fhr_0 = 15;
        int n_fhr_2 = 6;

        fhr_1 = (double)n_fhr_1/(n_fhr_1 + n_fhr_0 + n_fhr_2);
```

You have to cast one of the operands to double, this way it will calculate it as double.

Answer (score 2):

You can't simply devide integers, you will get 0 because of the rounding.
Try instead:

```
fhr_1 = ((double)(n_fhr_1))/(n_fhr_1 + n_fhr_0 + n_fhr_2);
```